# Apache poi cell format number

Tags: java, apache-poi, cell-formatting

I'm using cell format '#,##0.000000', but it shows extra zeros after decimal.
I need correct cell format to use for all following examples:

```
12.123000  => 12.123
12.120000  => 12.12
12.123456  => 12.123456
12.1234567 => 12.123457 
12         => 12
0          => 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, do you know what the `#` and the `0` in the format stand for?

Comment: i don't know exactly

Comment: The format is something from Excel, not really Apache POI. It is [documented here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4). I recommend reading that link. But the short version is: `0` means "Always have a digit here. If there isn't one, use zero". And `#` means "Optionally have a digit here. If there isn't one, don't show this place".

Comment: I'm using this format: #,###.######. Is it correct?

Comment: Well, have you tested it with those numbers you have asked about?

Comment: not working for last two test. In my test: "12 => 12,",  "0 => 0,"(showing with comma)

Comment: Open `Excel` and try whether you will find a number format which fulfills your requirements. You will not be able to find a such. So also `apache poi`will not be able. All your requirements except `12.1234567 => 12.123456 ` will be fullfilled by `General` format or `0`. But `12.1234567 => 12.123456 ` is not only a formatting issue but also the value is changed. This is not possible using formatting. A possible formatted output could only be `12.1234567 => 12.123457`.

Comment: 12.1234567 => 12.123456 is not possible. Yes, I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, most of those formats are just the `General` format.  If you need to have the `General` format but never expand beyond a certain number of decimal places, you will need two formats, and you can check in your code which format to use.  The second format could be something like `_(#,###.######_);`

You can also make formulas which truncate your numbers appropriately, but then you have to sacrifice precision in your values.